# Germany: Online Poker still worth it in 2021?

Tags: online, gaming-law

I just recently got into poker.
Since I have not yet played for real money online, I wonder if that even is lucrative in 2021 in Germany due to the Glücksspielstaatsvertrag?
Not only are online players strong, but there is also rake and now 5.3% tax on buy-ins which many online casinos relay to the player. For instance: Ggpoker taxes the stack with 5.3% when leaving a table.

Are there experienced German players here who want to share their perspective on the status quo?

Thanks a lot + happy grindin''

Comment: I won't put this as an answer as I can't say for sure, as it's more just from my experience of conversations I have had, but a lot of German pros and or successful players I know personally or know of have left Germany for this reason. A lot go to Austria as it's 0% tax. Similarly I know a few who reside in Ireland for the same reason. I think you need to remember that not only do you need to beat the rake, but you also need to beat the tax too, which I believe is 19% on winnings in Germany.

Comment: Or well I don't mean 'beat' the tax, as obviously the more you earn the more the tax, but I mean you need to make it worth your while. Unless of course you're just playing for fun, and in which case it shouldn't make a huge difference then.